# Как оптимизировать создание html страниц

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть проект на html, js, css (если без этого ни как, то можно привязать какой-то фреймворк или php/python ). Но не могу понять как реализовать автоматическое создание страниц, то-есть: предположим у меня новостной сайт, есть главная страница, где опубликованы все новости(аля карточки товаров), и у каждой новости есть своя отдельная html страница с большим объемом информацией. Как написать такую программу, что будет сама создавать страницы по шаблону, а не самому их делать.

Comment: Всё давно написано - не нужно изобретать велосипед. Посмотрите в сторону любой приличной системы управления контентом: Wordpress, Битрикс и т.д. Там это удобно реализовано: есть шаблонная часть сайта (хедер, футер, меню), а есть отдельные страницы публикаций, новостей, статей, которые генерятся автоматически.

Comment: @humster_spb, знаю, но у меня такая ситуация, что CMS я использовать не могу, поэтому и задаюсь подобным вопросом